# Will a MacBook work if bought from a different country?

Tags: macbook-pro, internationalization, apple-store

If I buy MacBook from Pakistan, will it work in Canada?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it will. Just be sure you want the keyboard layout in the country where you buy. Changing the physical keys is practically a non-stater. Everything software will reconfigure properly.